# Adding parentheses around subfig references

Tags: cross-referencing, formatting, subfloats

Say I have a figure with two subfloats inserted using the `subfig` package.  When I reference them with `\ref{myLabel}` I get this

> Figure 3.5a and 3.5b.

But what I want is this:

> Figure 3.5(a) and 3.5(b).

How can I add the parentheses?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package see sections 2.2.2 and 3 of [the documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}

\begin{document}
See Figure~\subref*{sf1} for more information.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfig 1]{\label{sf1} Contents of the sub-figure}
\qquad
\subfloat[Subfig 2]{\label{sf2} Contents of the sub-figure}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Subfigures with parentheses]

---

(Original answer)
Assuming you're using the [subfloat](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfloat/) package, section 4 of [its documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfloat/subfloat.pdf) indicates you can do something like:

```
\renewcommand*\thesubfloatfigure{\themainfigure(\alph{subfloatfigure})}
```

to put the sub-number in parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using subfig.  That's really my fault for leaving that unclear.

Comment: Edited for subfig. Not quite as straightforward, but easy enough.

Comment: I actually found this, which works for me well:                  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

Comment: This also works for `\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subcaption}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` does add parentheses in citations, but also seems to cause subfloat captions to be double-parenthesized: ((a)), ((b)), etc.

Comment: A bit confused, is `subfigure` is deprecated, or `subfig`?

Comment: For the subfig package, which LyX currently uses, the solution is to use @p_a_c 's suggestion in conjunction with \captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple}.

Answer (score 44):

If anyone came across this question and is using `subcaption`, here is a solution (borrowed from its excelent [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
Reference the sub-figure in full form: \ref{sf1}.
Referencing just the sub-figure parts: \subref{sf1} and \subref{sf2}.
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    Contents of the sub-figure
    \caption{Subfig 1}
    \label{sf1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    Contents of the sub-figure
    \caption{Subfig 2}
    \label{sf2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A figure}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, this caused double parenthesis before the caption of each subfigure. Adding the line: `\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}`, according to this answer helped http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135358/changing-the-formatting-of-subcaption-for-reference

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown option 'labelformat=simple' for package 'subcaption'.`

Comment: This helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]` options didn't work for me; the references still came out as, e.g., "1b". I had to use

```
\usepackage[caption=false,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

(I had to use `caption=false` because without it `subfig` makes the captions in my document class come out in the wrong style.) Does this seem all right to use? I did discover that under my way, you have to use `\subref*`, not `\subref`, if you want to auto-refer to something like "(a)" (with `\subref` you get "((a))").

Looking at the other answer again, I think I needed to do it this way because I had been using `\ref` for all my references to things like "Figure 1b". (I'd rather not change all my `\ref`'s to `\subref*`'s if I can avoid it.)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
See Figure~\ref{fig}\subref{sf1} for more information.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfig 1]{\label{sf1} Contents of the sub-figure}
\qquad
\subfloat[Subfig 2]{\label{sf2} Contents of the sub-figure}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could say some words about your solution. We don't expect an epic story, but something like "I did ... to achieve ..." would be nice. Anyway, welcome to Tex.sX, and thanks for contributing!

Comment: @TomBombadil : I guess this is obvious as he uses '\ref' and '\subref' together.

Comment: The output isn't obvious.  Easy enough to try it out, though.

Answer (score 1):

Combining ideas from some of the other answers, this is what works best for me:

```
\usepackage[caption=false,listofformat=subsimple,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

The line with `\renewcommand` now makes `\ref` work as I want, namely 1(a), so there is no need to use `\subref*` as in other solutions above.

This has now added double brackets in various places, which have to be removed. `\labelformat=simple` removes them from the subfigures, so these are now displayed as (a).

`\listofformat=subsimple` removes the double brackets from `\listoffigures` (which is only visible with `\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}`) and from `\subref`. So now I can use `\subref` if I just want (a).

`caption=false` is used because caption is incompatible with revtex, which is my class file, but shouldn't have any impact on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for editing my reply to improve the formatting. I am new to this :)