# change figure numbering in lyx

Tags: lyx

I have a lyx document with two figures side-by-side. right now everytime I reference to them I get them numbered like this 2a and 2b.
I want to make lyx to number them like this: 2(a) and 2(b). I want to add the parentheses.
Is there any way? maybe add something to the preamble?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: yes. I did exactly what this [link](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/FiguresSideBySide) suggests. I tried to look for a module to fix it but haven't found one.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Adding parentheses around subfig references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references).

In LyX, it seems you will have to put `\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}` in your preamble, and then you might need to use an ERT such as `Figure~\subref*{sf1}` in your document body for the reference.