# Changing the formatting of subcaption for reference

Tags: subcaption

```
   \usepackage{subcaption}
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
    Figure1
    \caption{Hello}~\label{fig:TBS}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{1\linewidth}
    Figure2
    \caption{Hello1}
    \end{subfigure}~\label{fig:TBSCompensate}
    \caption{BigHello}
    \end{figure}
```

Following is the what appears:
 [image]

When I use `Figure~\ref{fig:TBS}` to refer the figure
It appears `Figure 2a` in the pdf,
I wish that it could appear as `Figure 2(a)`, is the a way to tweat the formatting of caption for subfigure?

Comment: Would a combination of single references to the figure and the sub-figure like `\ref{fig:TBSCompensate}\subref{fig:TBS}`be an option?

Comment: Your way of specifying the labels is dubious: there should be no `~` and the `\label` command should go immediately after the `\caption` command it refers to.

Answer (score 22):

Your case will be handled in the `subcaption` documentation, section "References":

> But if you want detailed control on how the references will look like,
>   the options of `\DeclareCaptionSubType` are potentially not sufficient.
>   In this case one need to redefine these two macros on his/her own.
>   Some examples: If you want parentheses around the sub-figure part of
>   the reference, so they will look like ‘1(a)’, you may get them this
>   way:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
> \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
> ```
>
> (Note: Since `parens` is
>   the default label format you will get double parentheses in
>   sub-captions if you don't specify a different label format, e.g.,
>   `simple`.)