# Subcaption, subtable change the format of reference

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption

I am using `subcaption` to support multiple part tables (subtables).
The current reference format is `Table 1a`, I would like parentheses instead: `Table 1(a)`.

I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135358/changing-the-formatting-of-subcaption-for-reference) and the offered solution didn't work for me. It seems that the solution which is adding the following options only works for the `figure` and `subfigure` floats:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Is there anyway I can correct the format of references to the subtables? Below is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.49\textwidth}\centering
 %      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{myPicture}
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}.
        \caption{SubText 1}\label{subtab:p1}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.49\textwidth}\centering
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}.
        \caption{SubText 2}\label{subtab:p2}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Description referencing to \subref{subtab:p1} and
  \subref{subtab:p2}}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:1} has two parts \ref{subtab:p1} and \ref{subtab:p2}.
    
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

This shows the references and the labels incorrectly. The subcaption lables do not have parenthesis anymore and the references are still like 1a and 1b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType * [alph]{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=space}

\renewcommand\thesubtable{\thetable(\alph{subtable})}

 \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.49\textwidth}\centering
 % \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{myPicture}
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}
        \caption{SubText 1}\label{subtab:p1}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}[b]{.49\textwidth}\centering
        \rule{2cm}{2cm}
        \caption{SubText 2}\label{subtab:p2}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Description referencing to \ref{subtab:p1} and
  \ref{subtab:p2}}\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:1} has two parts \ref{subtab:p1} and \ref{subtab:p2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]