# How to add '( )' to the figure reference?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a figure that has three subfigures and I want to \ref them. I need them in this following format:

Fig. 1(a)

But when I use the \ref with the label of the subfigure a, it references this way:

Fig. 1a

I'm using the package \subcaption.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe the following question can help you: [Changing the formatting of subcaption for reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135358/134144)

Comment: I would use this format?                                 \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

    Fig.\ \ref{coffee1}

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{One cup of coffee.}
        \label{coffee1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{fig:More coffee.}
        \label{fig:coffee2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Coffee.}
      \label{fig:types_of_coffee}
    \end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Codewraith My pleasure!