# Anticlockwise or clockwise symbol (90°, 180°, 270°, 360°) in the caption

Tags: graphics, symbols, captions, automation, amssymb

I have this MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135441/121799
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
    \node[fill=orange,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
    corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
    \draw[very thick,orange] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
    \hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
    \draw[very thick,orange] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
    }}\par
    #3} 
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Incredibile}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz{%
    \node[text width=\linewidth-14pt,outer xsep=1.6pt,align=justify](MI){\textbf{\sffamily#1#2}#3};
    \draw[very thick,orange] (MI.north west) -- (MI.south west)
    (MI.north east) -- (MI.south east);
    }}\par
    } 
    \captionsetup{format=Incredibile}
    \captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
    \newcommand{\IncludeClippedGraphics}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[rounded corners=5pt,clip,preaction={draw=orange,very thick},inner sep=-2pt]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{fig:subim12}}
    \end{subfigure}\quad%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{\label{fig:subim29}}
    \end{subfigure}     
    \caption{Coordinate sferiche  $P(r,\varphi,\theta)$ nello spazio con linee coordinate e versori tangenti: notazione invertita tra $\varphi$ e $\theta$ rispetto a quella classica in Analisi Matematica.}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

with this screenshot:

[image]

Is it possible to put an orange `\blacktriangle`, before of the **Figure 1**, where every time that I have a new figure the symbol will rotate or in anticlockwise or in clockwise, starting from this position?

The example that I would to have is this below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to use `\newcount` math trick to perform required multiplication, so that each figure rotates the triangle an additional 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

The other key is that `\figurename` is the macro you need to update to reflect the desired caption label.  Therefore, my additions amounted to this in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\figcnt
\newcommand\figrot{\figcnt=\numexpr\dimexpr90\c@figure\relax-90\relax}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\figurename{\figrot\textcolor{orange}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{\figcnt}{$\blacktriangle$}} Figure}
```

The MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{caption}
    \usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135441/121799
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Sebastiano}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex]{%
    \node[fill=orange,text=white,font=\bfseries\sffamily\large,rounded
    corners=0.2em,minimum width=1.8em,minimum height=1.8em](M){#1};
    \draw[very thick,orange] (M.west) -- ++ (-1,0);}}%
    \hfill\hfill{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(R);
    \draw[very thick,orange] (M.east) -- (M.east-|R);
    }}\par
    #3} 
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{Incredibile}{%#1#2\par
    {\tikz{%
    \node[text width=\linewidth-14pt,outer xsep=1.6pt,align=justify](MI){\textbf{\sffamily#1#2}#3};
    \draw[very thick,orange] (MI.north west) -- (MI.south west)
    (MI.north east) -- (MI.south east);
    }}\par
    } 
    \captionsetup{format=Incredibile}
    \captionsetup[sub]{format=Sebastiano}
    \newcommand{\IncludeClippedGraphics}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[rounded corners=5pt,clip,preaction={draw=orange,very thick},inner sep=-2pt]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newcount\figcnt
\newcommand\figrot{\figcnt=\numexpr\dimexpr90\c@figure\relax-90\relax}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\figurename{\figrot\textcolor{orange}{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{\figcnt}{$\blacktriangle$}} Figure}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{\label{fig:subim12}}
    \end{subfigure}\quad%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \IncludeClippedGraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{\label{fig:subim29}}
    \end{subfigure}     
    \caption{Coordinate sferiche  $P(r,\varphi,\theta)$ nello spazio con linee coordinate e versori tangenti: notazione invertita tra $\varphi$ e $\theta$ rispetto a quella classica in Analisi Matematica.}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Next}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Third}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very kind Steven :-( I'm sorry. For me it is important only top, bottom, left and right :-( +1 surely...that I voted before.

Comment: @Sebastiano Give me a few minutes to edit

Comment: Yes, of course :-)...there is not hurry :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I will need more than a few minutes...trying to get it to work inside `\caption`.

Comment: Don't worry absolutely....I hope that you let calm :-)...you can improved your answer also to one week :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Done.  Still brute force using same technique.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have edited to improve the calculation of the rotation value of the orange triangle.

Comment: In this morning I have thought you....for the word "brute force"...but it is a good sense :-) or you have contacted HULK for the brute force ahahaahahahh. Always infinite thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano LOL, The idiomatic expression "brute force" in English refers to the use of a non-optimized method, getting the job done without using the right tool, or relying on a mathematical method that uses the maximum amount of calculation to achieve the result.  We sometimes also say, "it's close enough for government work,"