# Subcaption + clevered range parentheses

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I'm trying to have subcaption labels of the form `(a)`, `(b)`, etc. references of the form `fig. 1(a)`, and ranges of the form `figs. 1(a--c)`. I cannot seem to get the last requirement. Here's my MWE (adapting the second answer in [Adding parentheses around subfig references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references)) that gives me references of the form `figs. 1(a)--c)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,cleveref}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\crefrangeformat{figure}{figs.~#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\begin{document}
\cref{1,2,3}
\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{\label{1}}[0.3\textwidth][c]{}
\subcaptionbox{\label{2}}[0.3\textwidth][c]{}
\subcaptionbox{\label{3}}[0.3\textwidth][c]{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your declared formatting objective -- `figs. 1(a--c)` -- is not stylistically unambiguous. I think you'd be better off omitting the parentheses around the subcaption's numbers (letters) entirely, both for cross-references to single subfigures and to ranges of subfigures. Of course, you're perfectly free to use parentheses in the subfigures' captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{subfigure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
\cref{1}, \cref{1,2,3}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{\label{1}}[0.1\textwidth][c]{}\quad
\subcaptionbox{\label{2}}[0.1\textwidth][c]{}\quad
\subcaptionbox{\label{3}}[0.1\textwidth][c]{}
\label{Overall caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Why do you say the choice is not stylistically unambiguous? In what circumstance could I have "figs. #" followed with no space by a parenthetical, other than this one?

Comment: @bjorne - Questions of style are inherently subjective, so I’ll readily grant that you may see these matters from the way I do. When I read something like `figs. 1(a—c)`, my instinctual reaction is to start looking for a single subfigure labeled `(a—c)`. Then, after sime hesitation and stumbling around, I’d probably figure out that 3 separate subfigures are being cross-referenced...