# How to center align subfigures and bottom align the captions?

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, subfig

How can I center align the two subfigures and align the caption (a), (b) for the two figures like this? 
Assume that the image sizes are unknown. (or probably I can input it manually)
I saw some previous posts relating to this but they used minipages which I couldn't apply successfuly to my subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[]{subfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=30pt]{example-image-a}
\label{fig_first_case}}
\hfil
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=60pt]{example-image-b}
\label{fig_second_case}}
\caption{Example of two figures. (a) The first figure. (b) The second figure}
\label{fig_subfig}
\end{figure*}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `subfig` with the `caption=false` option, otherwise the caption style of `IEEEtran` would be overridden: this will annoy the copy editors of the journal you're submitting to (and maybe cause rejection).

For just one case you can do it manually:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\MakeRobust{\subref}

\newsavebox{\leftimage}
\newsavebox{\rightimage}
\newlength{\imageheight}
\newcommand{\placeimage}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\imageheight-\height)/2}{\usebox{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering

\sbox{\leftimage}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=30pt]{example-image-a}}
\sbox{\rightimage}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=60pt]{example-image-b}}

\setlength{\imageheight}{\ht\leftimage}
\ifdim\ht\rightimage>\imageheight
  \setlength{\imageheight}{\ht\rightimage}
\fi

\subfloat[]{\placeimage{\leftimage}\label{fig_first_case}}\hfil
\subfloat[]{\placeimage{\rightimage}\label{fig_second_case}}

\caption{%
  Example of two figures.
  \subref{fig_first_case}~The first figure.
  \subref{fig_second_case}~The second figure.
}
\label{fig_subfig}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both images are measured and the larger vertical size is determined. Then the boxes containing the images are raised by the appropriate amount.

Comment: This is very nice but I have some problem with reference hope you can help. It's related to my previous post. 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655002/how-to-refer-subfigure-with-parentheses-as-fig-1a-instead-of-fig-1a
I used `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` as Zxcvasdf mentioned to avoid double parenthesis like `((a))` and also refer to figure as `Fig. 1(a)` instead of `Fig. 1a` but now I got the problem like `Example of two figures. ((a)) The first figure. ((b)) The second figure.`

Comment: @emnha That's a known problem with `subfig`.

Comment: How can I fix this? `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` that Zxcvasdf suggested work for reference but it doesn't remove double parenthesis in the caption of your solution.

Comment: @emnha Did you look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16291/4427 ?

Comment: I did and used `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` that Zxcvasdf suggested and it fixed the problem of reference in the text. However, it doesn't work in figure caption in your code.

Comment: I solved it with `\subref*{}` in the caption!

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with the `floatrow` package:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[]{subfig}
    \usepackage{stfloats}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure*}[!t]
    \floatsetup{heightadjust=all, valign=c}
    \centering
    \ffigbox{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox{\caption{}\label{fig_first_case}}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=30pt]{example-image-a}
    }
    \hfil
    \ffigbox{\caption{}\label{fig_second_case}}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=60pt]{example-image-b}
    }
    \end{subfloatrow}}{\caption{Example of two figures. (a) The first figure. (b) The second figure}}
    \end{figure*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can I keep the same caption style as the original like `Fig. 1` instead of `Fig. 1:`? The caption style is not compatible with IEEEtran.

Comment: I got some other warning as well from overleaf: `Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Package caption Warning: \setcaptionsubtype without \DeclareCaptionSubType. This is not designed to work; you could try replacing the `subfig' package with `subcaption' to resolve this problem which occurred on input line 18. See the caption package documentation for explanation`

Comment: `floatrow` cooperates with the `caption` package . You might try `\captionsetup{labelsep=none}`.

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: @emnha: either in the preamble, or just after the beginnning of the environment if it is to be used only once.

Answer (score 1):

In case IEEE has a problem with floatrow...

The tricky ibt was matching the spacing used by `\subfloat` (NOT `\abovecaptionskip` or `\belowcaptionskip`).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}% for \thesubfigure

\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\tabcolsep=0.0833\linewidth% 0.5\linewidth / 6 (3 equal gaps)
\belowcaptionskip=-\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=30pt]{example-image-a}} &
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, height=60pt]{example-image-b}} \\
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig_first_case}\raisebox{-1ex}{(\thesubfigure)} &
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{fig_second_case}\raisebox{-1ex}{(\thesubfigure)}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Example of two figures. (a) The first figure. (b) The second figure}
\label{fig_subfig}
\end{figure*}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I keep the caption style as `Fig. 1` instead of `Fig. 1:` which is not compatible with IEEEtran?

Comment: You can use `\caption{}` to get `Fig.1` with no colon, but adding a colon before the title **is** IEEE standard.